# Boost::Spirit mini_c tutorial

Tags: c++, boost, boost-spirit

Is there any tutorial describing mini_c example from boost::spirit? It looks as good example of using `grammar` from boost::spirit::qi, but it's rather complex one and some guide through the code would be helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

None that I know of. However, the mini_c example is step 9 in a series of calculator examples. Therefore, if you start working from calc1.cpp up to mini_c (or even the new 'conjure' examples now added to SVN) you shouldn't have a hard time understanding what's going on.